# Youtube Java API. Make YouTubeService without Login

Tags: java, api, youtube

I am beginning to learn how to use the Java Youtube API, but I have run into a problem. I am following the tutorials given by Google:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java.html

The problem is, is that you seem to need a YouTubeService object to make queries. It seems like the only way to make this is with the user logging in. How can I make queries without having the user log in?

```
    YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService();  //???? How do I make a proper YouTubeService without login. There is no constructor without and parameters.
    String search = "Dubstep";

    try {
        YouTubeQuery query = new YouTubeQuery(new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos"));
        query.setOrderBy(YouTubeQuery.OrderBy.RELEVANCE);
        query.setFullTextQuery(search);
        query.setSafeSearch(YouTubeQuery.SafeSearch.NONE);

        VideoFeed videoFeed = service.query(query, VideoFeed.class);
        printVideoFeed(videoFeed, true);  // Eclipse also doesn't recognize this method.

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am really confused by this, and I really need this help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is your problem? There is a constructor where you can pass your application name:

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/youtube/YouTubeService.html

Just call this:

```
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService("The name of my application");
```